# Is it generally the case that $\mathbb{E}[X|Z>0]\cdot \mathbb{P}(Z>0)=\mathbb{E}[X]$ for random variables $X$ and $Z$?

Tags: probability

For arbitrary random variables $X$ and $Z$, it generally the case that $\mathbb{E}[X|Z>0]\cdot \mathbb{P}(Z>0)=\mathbb{E}[X]$? Or does this normally hold with restrictions? I am trying to use the law of total expectations for this.

Comment: It is easy to come up with counter examples. Let $X$, $Z$ tow independent Bernoulli 0-1 random variables with parameter $p=1/2$. Then $E[X]=\frac12$ while $E[X|Z>0]P[Z>0]=E[X]P[Z>0]=\frac14$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement does not hold in general. What holds is:

$$E[X]=E[X|Z>0]P(Z>0)+E[X|Z\le 0]P(Z\le 0)$$

From which you may see that if $E[X|Z\le 0]\ne 0$ and $P(Z\le 0)>0$ your statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

From a measure-theoretic perspective, what $\mathbb{E}[X|Z>0]\cdot \mathbb{P}[Z>0]$ is equal to is the integral of $X$ over the event $\{Z>0\}$, that is: $$\int_{\{Z>0\}}X\,\mathrm d\mathbb P.$$
To get the total expectation $\mathbb E[X]$, you need to integrate over the unrestricted sample space: $$\int X\,\mathrm d\mathbb P.$$